# Number Theoretic Polynomial Question Involving the Derivative

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, and let $p$ be a prime. If I know that
1. $p \nmid b$ and
2. $p^{2} \mid f(a+bp)-f(a)$,
how can I show that $p \mid f'(a)$ (the derivative of $f$ at $a$)?

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem,
$$
(a+bp)^k = a^k + k a^{k-1} (bp) + (bp)^2 c_k
$$
where $c_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore,
$$
f(a+bp) = \sum a_k(a+bp)^k
= \sum a_k a^k + \sum k a_k a^{k-1} (bp) +  (bp)^2 \sum a_k c_k
\\= f(a) + f'(a)(bp) + (bp)^2 c
$$
for some $c \in \mathbb Z$. The claim follows at once.

Comment: I wish I could just use Taylor's expansion:
$$
f(a+bp) = f(a) + f'(a)(bp) + f''(a)(bp)^2 /2 + \cdots
$$ but the fractions get in the way.